# tcl tk tablelist How to get column name

Tags: tcl

I am using tablelist

```
tablelist::tablelist .t -columns { 0 "Name" 0 "Age" 0 "sex" 0 "ROLLNO" }  -width 250 -height 15 -selectmode single
```

I need to add few more columns after checking there is no duplication.

```
.t insertcolumnlist 4 {0 "account" }
.t insertcolumnlist 4 {0 "ROLLNO" }
```

Now, the `ROLLNO` is duplicated.
How to get the current column list from the table.

Thanks,
Nagaraj.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to read the `tablelist::tablelist` manual. It contains a lot of interesting info. The command

```
.t cget -columns
```

does just that (returns the columns list in triplets `width`, `header`, `adjustment`). Or you could use more general

```
.t configure -columns
```

command which returns a list which fully describes the `-column` option, including its class, value by default and the current value.